# How to find collection records contains string in objects of array in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

I have MongoDB collection with multiple records. Each record has an array which contains objects with multiple fields.

**I have collection like below:**

```
[{
    "name" : "Karthik Thurairaja"
    "universities" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Anna University",
            "city" : "Chennai"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Punjab University",
            "city" : "Chandigarh"
        },
        {
            "name" : "University of Delhi",
            "city" : "New Delhi"
        }
    ],
},
{
    "name" : "Sathish Kumar"
    "universities" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Anna University",
            "city" : "Chennai"
        },
        {
            "name" : "University of Hyderabad",
            "city" : "Hyderabad"
        },
        {
            "name" : "University of Delhi",
            "city" : "New Delhi"
        }
    ],
}]
```

**I need to find all the records universities city is equal to Chennai.**

**I have tried query like below:**

```
Collection.find({ universities.city : "Chennai" }).exec(...);
```

Comment: `"universities.city": "Chennai"`

Comment: check : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `$elemMatch` query to achieve this.

`Collection.find({ universities: { $elemMatch: { city: "Chennai" } } }).exec(...);`